# why does Scala function accepts case class type for a function argument?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Consider the code block.

```
class Evaluation {
  def evaluate= {
    println("Charlie...")
  }
}
case class Dept(name:String) extends Evaluation

def depEval(name:String,f:(String) => Evaluation) ={
  println(name)
  f(name).evaluate
}
depEval("abc", Dept)
```

Why does Dept can be passed as a Funtion1 type? Is it that, Scala does not checks for the type before resolving the arguments.

Consider other snippet

```
def matchingCase(f: String => Evaluation)= {
  println(f.toString())
  f match {
    case Dept => println("function type matched")
  }
}

matchingCase((x: String)=> Dept(x))
```

Whereas in the above code scala gives a match error, as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The companion object of a case class extends `FunctionX[T1, T2, <CaseClass>]` so that you can use it to construct instances of the case class.

So, for example, if you have a case class

```
case class Foo(i: Int, s: String)
```

the compiler will generate a companion object

```
object Foo extends (Int, String) ⇒ Foo with Product2[Int, String] {
  def apply(i: Int, s: String) = new Foo(i, s)

  // and some other stuff such as equals, hashCode, copy
}
```

This allows you to construct an instance of `Foo` like this:

```
Foo(42, "Hello")
```

instead of

```
new Foo(42, "Hello")
```

So, to conclude: the reason, why you can pass the `Dept` companion object as a function is because it *is* a function.

Comment: Worth adding that it's easy to break this behavior by defining the companion explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

`Dept` is not a "case class type", it's the companion `object` for the case class. It extends `Function1` (and has `.apply` method, that's part of the interface), so you can use it wherever a function is expected.

The second snipped fails because `{ x => Dept(x) }` is it's own anonymous function, not `Dept` object.

Comment: Actually, `Dept` is a `String => Dept`, there is no eta-expansion. In the second case, the function literal is not `Dept`.

Answer (score 0):

It has a lot of sense, because if you just give as paramenter `Dept` it will behave ass a function that takes a String as parameter, and return an instance of the class Dept, meaning a Dept object (It is like give the `new` or apply function as parameter), look that the following code is valid also:

```
val c: Dept.type = Dept

val dep = c("Name1")

dep
```

res1: Dept = Dept(Name1)

```
dep.evaluate
```

Charlie...
res2: Unit = ()